# ASP using GetObject to invoke ADSI methods

Tags: asp-classic, com, ldap, adsi

I have a classic ASP site running under a domain account application pool context, which is using windows-auth for the front end user validation.  The code is able to query AD via LDAP and ADSI just fine, however when trying to obtain an object reference to something like a computer object using GetObject, it is unable to do so.  I read this [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278836] but I'm confused about why it doesn't seem to work under the application pool context when the account is (a) a domain user, and (b) has permissions to perform the actions (move computer from one OU to another OU).  Is there another way to make it work without rewriting the site in ASP.NET or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.  I realized that a better option for this particular task is to queue up the requested operation in a database table and process it using a separate, scheduled task.  That allows for recording both the request and the result of the process completion.